# PostgreSQL date() with timezone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I'm having an issue selecting dates properly from Postgres - they are being stored in UTC, but 
not converting with the Date() function properly.

Converting the timestamp to a date gives me the wrong date if it's past 4pm PST.

`2012-06-21` should be `2012-06-20` in this case.

The `starts_at` column datatype is `timestamp without time zone`. Here are my queries:

Without converting to PST timezone:

```
Select starts_at from schedules where id = 40;

      starts_at      
---------------------
 2012-06-21 01:00:00
```

Converting gives this:

```
Select (starts_at at time zone 'pst') from schedules where id = 40;
        timezone        
------------------------
 2012-06-21 02:00:00-07
```

But neither convert to the correct date in the timezone.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I don't see the *exact* type of `starts_at` in your question. You really should include this information, it is the key to the solution. I'll have to guess.

PostgreSQL *always* stores UTC time for the type `timestamp with time zone` internally. Input and output (display) are adjusted to the current `timezone` setting or to the given time zone. The effect of [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) also changes with the underlying data type. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

If you extract a `date` from type [`timestamp [without time zone]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), you get the date for the current time zone. The day in the output will be the same as in the display of the `timestamp` value.

If you extract a `date` from type [`timestamp with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (`timestamptz` for short), the time zone offset is "applied" first. You still get the date for the current time zone, which agrees with the *display* of the timestamp. The same point in time translates to the next day in parts of Europe, when it is past 4 p.m. in California for instance. To get the date for a certain time zone, apply `AT TIME ZONE` first.

Therefore, what you describe at the top of the question contradicts your example.

Given that `starts_at` is a **`timestamp [without time zone]`** and the time on your server is set to the local time. Test with:

```
SELECT now();
```

Does it display the same time as a clock on your wall? If yes (and the db server is running with correct time), the `timezone` setting of your current session agrees with your local time zone. If no, you may want to visit the setting of `timezone` in your `postgresql.conf` or your client for the session. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

Be aware that the `timezone` offset used the opposite **sign** of what's displayed in timestamp literals. See:

- [Peculiar time zone handling in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795645/peculiar-time-zone-handling-in-a-postgres-database/40797123#40797123)

To get your local date from `starts_at` just

```
SELECT starts_at::date
```

Tantamount to:

```
SELECT date(starts_at)
```

BTW, your local time is at UTC-7 right now, not UTC-8, because daylight savings time is in effect (not among the brighter ideas of the human race).

Pacific Standard TIME (PST) is normally 8 hours "earlier" (bigger `timestamp` value) than UTC (Universal Time Zone), but during daylight saving periods (like now) it can be 7 hours. That's why `timestamptz` is displayed as `2012-06-21 02:00:00`**`-07`** in your example. The construct `AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` takes daylight saving time into account. These two expressions yield different results (one in winter, one in summer) and may result in different dates when cast:

```
SELECT '2012-06-21 01:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
     , '2012-12-21 01:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
```

Comment: This is sort of correct - 'PST' doesn't take daylight savings into account, see John Rennpferd's answer about using "US/Pacific" vs "PST" or "PDT"

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter what would happen if I typecast a string of just date by `SELECT '2018-09-17'::date`? Would it assume the result to be in UTC or in local time?

Comment: A `date` is just that: a date. No time zone involved. There is no information *where* on earth the date is supposed to be. When casting (explicitly or implicitly) to `timestamp` / `timestamptz`, the time zone becomes relevant again.

Answer (score 84):

Basically what you want is:

```
$ select starts_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' from schedules where id = 40
```

I got the solution from this article is below, which is straight GOLD!!! It explains this non-trivial issue very clearly, give it a read if you wish to understand pstgrsql TZ management better.

[Expressing PostgreSQL timestamps without zones in local time](https://icu.iorahealth.com/blog/2012/05/07/expressing-postgresql-timestamps-without-zones-in-local-time/)

Here is what is going on. First you should know that 'PST timezone is 8 hours behind UTC timezone so for instance Jan 1st 2014, 4:30 PM PST (Wed, 01 Jan 2014 16:00:30 -0800) is equivalent to Jan 2nd 2014, 00:30 AM UTC (Thu, 02 Jan 2014 00:00:30 +0000). Any time after 4:00pm in PST slips over to the next day, interpreted as UTC.

Also, as Erwin Brandstetter mentioned above, postresql has two type of timestamps data type, one with a timezone and one without.
If your timestamps include a timezone, then a simple:

```
$ select starts_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' from schedules where id = 40
```

will work. However if your timestamp is timezoneless, executing the above command will not work, and you must FIRST convert your timezoneless timestamp to a timestamp with a timezone, namely a UTC timezone, and ONLY THEN convert it to your desired 'PST' or 'US/Pacific' (which are the same up to some daylight saving time issues. I think you should be fine with either).

Let me demonstrate with an example where I create a timezoneless timestamp. Let's assume for convenience that our local timezone is indeed 'PST' (if it weren't then it gets a tiny bit more complicated which is unnecessary for the purpose of this explanation).

Say I have:

```
$ select timestamp '2014-01-2 00:30:00' AS a, 
         timestamp '2014-01-2 00:30:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS b,  
         timestamp '2014-01-2 00:30:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS c, 
         timestamp '2014-01-2 00:30:00' AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS d
```

This will yield:

```
"a"=>"2014-01-02 00:30:00"   (This is the timezoneless timestamp)
"b"=>"2014-01-02 00:30:00+00" (This is the UTC TZ timestamp, note that up to a timezone, it is equivalent to the timezoneless one)
"c"=>"2014-01-01 16:30:00" (This is the correct 'PST' TZ conversion of the UTC timezone, if you read the documentation postgresql will not print the actual TZ for this conversion)
"d"=>"2014-01-02 08:30:00+00"
```

The last timestamp is the reason for all the confusion regarding converting timezoneless timestamp from UTC to 'PST' in postgresql. When we write:

```
timestamp '2014-01-2 00:30:00' AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS d
```

We are taking a timezoneless timestamp and try to convert it to 'PST TZ (we indirectly assume that postgresql will understand that we want it to convert the timestamp from a UTC TZ, but postresql has plans of its own!). In practice, what postgresql does is it takes the timezoneless timestamp ('2014-01-2 00:30:00) and treats it as if it WERE ALREADY a 'PST' TZ timestamp (i.e: 2014-01-2 00:30:00 -0800) and converts that to UTC timezone!!! So it actually pushes it 8 hours ahead instead of back! Thus we get (2014-01-02 08:30:00+00).

Anyway, this last (un-intuitive) behavior is the cause of all confusion. Read the article if you want a more thorough explanation, I actually got results which are a bit different then their on this last part, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: I would say this is a better accepted answer, due to the extra info on "first converting to UTC", as this was the issue I was facing (timestamp without timezone quirks).

Comment: I find the same results using `starts_at::timestamptz at time zone "pst"` (skip the at `at time zone 'utc'` middle-man by casting with tz) - which was suggested in an answer below, but was my hunch before reading this. Are these indeed technically the same?

Comment: The cited article moved to https://icu.iorahealth.com/blog/2012/05/07/expressing-postgresql-timestamps-without-zones-in-local-time/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150308140507/http://icu.iorahealth.com/blog/2012/05/07/expressing-postgresql-timestamps-without-zones-in-local-timee/

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old one but You may want to consider using AT TIME ZONE "US/Pacific" when casting to avoid any PST/PDT issues.  So

```
SELECT starts_at::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE "US/Pacific" 
  FROM schedules 
 WHERE ID = '40';
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct if you need historical dates to represent the actual time they happened.