# Performing division with PostgreSQL / json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, division, integer-division

I have written a simple query against a table in a Postgres database that contains a column "manifest" of type `json`. Each cell contains a very long value and I am extracting the numerical value for "size".

I need to create a new column (perhaps call it "size in MB"), and perform division against size. Specifically, I need to take the value of size and divide it by 1024, two times.  I have tried every example I can find to no avail.

Here is my current query, and a small snippet of the result:

```sql
select customers.name, images.customer_id, images.captured_at, images.name,
 manifest -> 'size' as image_size
from public.images
inner join public.customers on customers.id = images.customer_id
where (captured_at > current_date - interval '12 months')
order BY captured_at desc
```

```
Name       customer_id   captured_at   name         image_size
Acme Inc   12345         2022-05-31    Central HMA  628032520
```

The goal is to take `image_size`, divide by 1024 two times, and store the result in a new column called "size in MB". So in this case, the result of the math would be 598.

Comment: `...manifest -> 'size' as image_size, manifest -> 'size'/1024/1024 as size _in_mb...`? Or simpler: `...manifest -> 'size'/1048576 as size _in_mb...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a scalar value (not another `json`) use the [**`->>`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) (not `->`).
That returns type `text`. So you also need to **cast** before doing math on the number:

```
(manifest ->> 'size')::bigint  -- or numeric? see below!
```

See:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

You *could* do [integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE), which **truncates**, computing *598* like you projected:

```
SELECT 628032520 / 1024 / 1024  -- 598  -- truncated!
```

Casting to a floating point number or `numeric` avoids integer division and shows your sample value to be much closer to *599*:

```
SELECT 628032520.0 / 2^20  -- 598.9384841918945313  -- precise
```

The [numeric constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) `123` resolves to type `integer`, while `123.0` (containing a point `.`) resolves to `numeric`.
And `1024 * 1024` = `1048576` = `2^20`.

Maybe round? Or keep two fractional digits?

```
SELECT round(628032520.0 / 2^20)     -- 599    -- rounded
     , round(628032520.0 / 2^20, 2)  -- 599.94
```

**But** consider the built-in function [`pg_size_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) instead which is made for this very purpose:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(628032520.0)  -- 599 MB  -- formatted text
     , pg_size_pretty(232520.0)     -- 227 kB
```

So:

```sql
SELECT c.name AS customer, i.customer_id, i.captured_at, i.name AS image
     , pg_size_pretty((c.manifest ->> 'size')::numeric) AS image_size
FROM   public.images i
JOIN   public.customers c ON c.id = i.customer_id
WHERE  captured_at > date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '12 months'
ORDER  BY captured_at DESC;
```

Should give you:

```
customer   customer_id   captured_at   image        image_size
Acme Inc   12345         2022-05-31    Central HMA  599 MB
```

I also fixed a couple other issues with your query.

Assuming `captured_at` is type `timestamptz` (like it probably should be), `current_date` would introduce a dependency on time zone setting of the session, which is a sneaky, unnecessary source of corner-case errors. See:

- [PostgreSQL date() with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126037/postgresql-date-with-timezone/11148548#11148548)

And "name" is not a good name.

Comment: Thank you very much, Erwin, for such a detailed answer.  As I mentioned, I'm still learning and appreciate the push.   Trying your modifications, I receive "cannot cast type json to numeric."  And when I tried a few things, I received another error about "function pg_size_pretty(json) does not exist."  Is this a function I need to create?