# calculate column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

To the alter column I want update values calculates from two another columns. I write:

```
UPDATE daily_eu SET total_cases_per_million = (total_cases/population)*1000000;
```

Result is for all records value:

> 0.000

How to fix to give correct result of my calculation?

Comment: Show your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). You probably fell victim to integer division.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid [integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) (which truncates fractional digits):

```sql
UPDATE daily_eu
SET    total_cases_per_million = total_cases * 1000000.0 / population;
```

The numeric constant with a fractional digit (`1000000.0`) resolves to type `numeric` instead of `integer`, avoiding integer division.
It's also typically more precise to multiply first.

Related:

- [Performing division with PostgreSQL / json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454694/performing-division-with-postgresql-json/72456140#72456140)
- [Calculating rates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031806/calculating-rates-in-postgresql/50033357#50033357)