# Convert a postgres timestamp with no timezone column to a date

Tags: postgresql

Given a postgres table with a column that is a `timestamp without time zone`

```
 select "columnWithoutTimeZone" from my_table
```

Which results in:

```
 columnWithoutTimeZone
 Jun 11, 2022, 1:15:06 AM
 Jun 11, 2022, 1:15:06 AM
```

**How can the date component of timestamp be extracted?**

I tried

```
select to_date("columnWithoutTimeZone") from my_table
```

But this produced an error:

```
ERROR: function to_date(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

There is a [similar stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126037/postgresql-date-with-timezone), but that deals with timezone conversions.  I am simply trying to extract the `Jun 11, 2022` that is presently represented in the column.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```sql
select "columnWithoutTimeZone"::date from my_table
```

Comment: ::date is a PostgreSQL shortcut for CAST(column AS DATE)